# JPA: common entity used by many other entity classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have searched quite a bit through other SO questions without luck, possibly due to me using the incorrect search terms.

I would like to create an entity (Note), that can be "attached" to any other Entity in our inheritance tree.

eg:

```
@Entity
class Note extends AbstractEntity {
    String title
    String message;
    AbstractEntity relatedItem;
}

@Entity
class EntityOne extends AbstractEntity {
}

@Entity
class EntityTwo extends AbstractEntity {
}
```

I know that I could do the following:

```
@Entity
class Note extends AbstractEntity {
    String title
    String message;
}

@Entity
class EntityOne extends AbstractEntity {
    List<Note> notes;
}

@Entity
class EntityTwo extends AbstractEntity {
    List<Note> notes;
}
```

but this will then result in tables like:

```
Note - ID, title, message
EntityOne_Note - entityOne_ID, note_ID 
EntityTwo_Note - entityTwo_ID, note_ID
```

and requires me to update the entities if we wish to add note support to them.

For some reason it just feels better to have a table like:

```
Note - ID, title, message, relatedItem_ID, relatedItem_DTYPE
```

I dont even mind a single extra table:

```
Note - ID, title, message
AbstractEntity_Note - relatedItem_ID, relatedItem_DTYPE, note_ID
```

thoughts?

Comment: I think there is a catch here. If I understood right, you want to have notes attached to information in other tables. Then, you want to reuse notes for all tables. I believe, and correct me if I'm' wrong, that EntityOne notes are different of EntityTwo ntoes, which means that they should be stored in different tables. In a different scenario, you could relate EntityOne and EntityTwo to the same User table (for example) as in this case, users are users everywhere but notes for one table are different of notes for another table, for as much they have the same structure.

Comment: I am not sure if they are different. Take a Post-it for example. All Post-it's are the same, except what is written on them. A Post-it can be stuck on anything. That is essentially what I want to model

Comment: Well, there is not right or wrong when modelling something. My User example follows your modelling idea. And I'm sure the note model is going to work as well. I would be concerned when more tables join the party and more notes need to be attached to those new tables. You might need to record an extra information for a note in one table. Then you would add an extra column that other notes wouldn't need breaking the normalization rule number just god knows. I know nothing about your requirements and I could be just talking bllocks here. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many relatedItem_DTYPE you have, if they are few (for example 2) you can use an approach like this

```
@Entity
class Note extends AbstractEntity{
public String title
public String message;
@ManyToOne
EntityOne e1;
@ManyToOne
EntityTwo e2;
}
```

If you wish to have the references to the notes in Entities classes, just add a field to keep trace of the reverse relation.

You will end up to classes like these:

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne{
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="e1")
public List<Note> notes;
}

@Entity
public class EntityTwo{
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="e2")
public List<Note> notes;
}
```

Or you can try to create the inheritance using the `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` and see how Hibernate handle that :D.
By the way keep in mind that just saving the couple relatedItem_ID, relatedItem_DTYPE means that a note can belongs only to one instance of a particular type.